# how and what is window messaging in windows form application

Tags: .net, winforms, c#-4.0, messaging

Can anyone help me to understand the window messaging. Any reference or guide to understand all the concepts of this.
i try to google and get this link [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms644950(VS.85).aspx) but i not get it. Is any other link that will help to understand all the process with example.

Comment: Here is a good MSDN resource about [Windows and Messages](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632586(v=vs.85).aspx) which contains useful contents about [Messages and Message Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632590(v=vs.85).aspx), [Window Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632593(v=vs.85).aspx), [Hooks](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632589(v=vs.85).aspx) and so on.

Comment: This is off-topic for SO!

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: 
http://winprog.org/tutorial/message_loop.html

This is however, win32 programming, using the message pump, unmanaged code. Are you sure this is what you're after?